# Reactjs not getting installed

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors

I have been trying to install React on my pc using both the methods `npx` and `npm` 
 but even then my terminal (VSCode) is throwing this error. I am unable to start my custom react app. 
I have checked other responses but I was not satisfied.

```
My current node version is 12.16.2
```

```
My current npm version is 6.14.8
```

My package.json file is :

```
"name": "myapp",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
 "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
 "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
 "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
 "react": "^16.13.1",
 "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
 "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
},
"scripts": {
 "start": "react-scripts start",
 "build": "react-scripts build",
 "test": "react-scripts test",
 "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
 "extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
 "production": [
   ">0.2%",
   "not dead",
   "not op_mini all"
 ],
 "development": [
   "last 1 chrome version",
   "last 1 firefox version",
   "last 1 safari version"
 ]
}
}
```

[image]

**I have been stuck for hours now**. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Actually, you have that error message in your console. The exclamation point is not allowed in your file path.

Comment: @fooiey Thanks for the clarification. Issue Solved.